# Creating a list of all the strings of one column JPA repository

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, tablecolumn

I have a table for employees info. The primary key of the employee table is an ID and the other columns of the table are all strings including: first name, last name, and email. I am trying to create endpoints for various queries. I have List< Employee > findAll(); which gives me a list of all the employees with their names and emails. I also have List< Employee > findEmployeeByEmail(String email); which gives me the employee's info with the inputed email.

What I need help with is creating a List of every email from all of the employees. I tried List< String > findAllEmail(); and List< String > findEmail(); and both fail. Any tips on what "find" command I could just to just create a list of strings of all employee emails? Or would I not use a find command at all?

Thanks

Comment: You just need to write a trivial JPQL query, and annotate your method with `@Query`.

Comment: As you are using Spring Data, Projections should do what you need.https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections